# Select window created using JavaScript

Tags: robotframework, selenium2library

In My Robot Script , After clicking on Edit Description link a window get opens (i.e. Java Script Window) Images here
Image 1::
[image]

Image 2:: Window image Along with Page Source
[image]

What i need is a. Select the window (java script)
b. Enter text into Text Area and click Ok.

I tried to use Select Window new/ Select window   Description  But control is waiting infinite @ Select Window key word its not moving forward.  I have to kill Control forcefully.

```
    *** Settings ***
Documentation    Suite description
Library  Selenium2Library       run_on_failure=Nothing
Library  Collections

*** Test Cases ***
Log into Command center
    [Tags]    DEBUG
    open browser        http://11.8.180.***/BCC     ie

    input text          xpath=//*[@id='LoginName']   User
    input password      Password   Pwd@123
    click element       LoginBtn
    wait until keyword succeeds     30 sec       5 sec     page should contain element      AppTitle
    sleep   3s
    ${Title}    Get Page Title
    log  ${Title}
    Navigation to Usrs
    Click on Window popup and enter text

CloseBrowser
    close all browsers

*** Keywords ***
Click on Window popup and enter text
    Click Link   //*[@id="aspnetForm"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/a
    Sleep  5s
Select Window By Unique Identifier Element With Delay   //*[@id="descript"]

Select Window By Unique Identifier Element With Delay
    [Arguments]  ${element}   ${delay_time}=10
    sleep  ${delay_time}
    @{wins}=  Get Window Handles
    Log  ${wins}<--these are window names   console=true
    :FOR  ${windowName}  IN  @{wins}
    \   Log   ${windowName}   console=true
    \   run keyword and ignore error  Select Window  ${windowName}
    \   ${found_flag}=   run keyword and return status  page should contain  ${element}
    \   Run keyword if  ${found_flag}  input text  ${element}  this is text
    \   exit for loop if  ${found_flag}

Get Page Title
    Log  Control came to GET PAGE TITLE
    run keyword and return  Get Title

Navigation to Usrs
    Go to   http://11.8.180.***/BCC/role.aspx
```

Any Idea how to select new window? and enter text hit okay.

```
A.Get Window Identifiers --> Jus hangs it neither moves nor throw any error 
B. Get Window Names gives this error {URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it>..}. 
C. Get Window Handles returns this {    [u'b0ce0f28-f6d4-4943-93f7-f65fd5f1de2a', u'c0442110-4ea9-40a4-b126-eee09d9f3eb0']} 
I am not sure how to identify which window have these id's
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What does "no luck" mean? Can you show the actual code you used, and any error message you got when running the code?

Comment: Updated Error message...

Comment: I still don't see any code, and I don't think you provided the complete, actual error message.

Comment: I added code, I tried to capture the error. But Execution control never stopped. It was waiting at Select Window   Title=Description

Comment: Have you tried any of the Get List of Windows, Get Window Names or any of [the other ones](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Get%20Window%20Handles)?

Comment: Yes,  A.Get Window Identifiers --> Jus hangs it neither moves nor throw any error  B.  Get Window Names gives this error {URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it>..}.  C. Get Window Handles returns this { [u'b0ce0f28-f6d4-4943-93f7-f65fd5f1de2a', u'c0442110-4ea9-40a4-b126-eee09d9f3eb0']} --> I am not sure how to identify which window have these id's

Comment: First: add the above information to your question. Reading code in comments doesn't work. As for your question. In the SeleniumLibrary Keyword documentation for the Keyword [Get Windows Handles](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Get%20Window%20Handles) it refers to [Select Windows](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Select%20Window) which has an example for you to work with. Though since you're getting 2 handles in a list I'd adjust the example to: `${excludes[0]}` or `${excludes[1]}` to refer to the right one. Then use `Log Title`.

Comment: @A.Kootstra, Tried doing same but S2L waiting infinite to Select Windows. Updated code in the Q

Comment: It shouldn't wait forever to process the `Select Window` keyword. I've tried the examples and they work for me. Can you update your question with what OS, Browser Version, IEDriverServer, Selenium and SeleniumLibrary you're using?

Answer (score 0):

It should be recognized as new window in your browser, so you can use:

```
Select Window   Description
```

Comment: As highlighted in the question, these keywords have been tried and are not working within the current context. So, this can not be the correct answer.

Comment: I mean what about using just Description without Title=

Comment: If it's a question or an unproven suggestion to the original poster, then please create a comment on the question. To me this sounds like a question.